Use R function separate() on all dataframes in a list
I have a (large) list of dataframes each with a single column. I would like to split these into 20 columns by a delimiter. On a single dataframe:
file2=file1 %>% 
    separate(V1,into=c(paste0("column_",letters[1:20])),sep="\\|")

Is there a way to apply this to the entire list? I have tried:
map(filelist, ~ separate(.x, into=c(paste0("column_",letters[1:20])),sep="\\|")) 

Which returned:
Caused by error in `separate()`:
! `col` is absent but must be supplied.

Alternatively, is something other than separate() that would be more efficient?

Read the error message: you need to specify col, but you've only given it data, into, and sep. Try map(filelist, ~ separate(.x, V1, into=c(paste0("column_",letters[1:20])),sep="\\|")). Note that the pipe %>% gives file1 as the first argument to separate, so in your first example V1 is taken as the second argument (col), but in your second example, you don't give a second unnamed argument to be matched to col.

Can also use separate_wider_delim since separate is superseded. map(filelist, ~ separate_wider_delim(.x, cols=V1, names=c(paste0("column_", letters[1:20])), delim="|"))

Both comments would be a good answer.

No data was provided, so I'll create a minimal dataset that I think resembles the OP's and gives the desired output.
library(tidyverse)

filelist <- list(data1=tibble(V1=c("1|2|3|4|5", "6|7|8|9|10")),
                 data2=tibble(V1=c("6|7|8|9|10", "11|12|13|14|15")),
                 data3=tibble(V1=c("16|17|18|19|20", "21|22|23|24|25")))> 
filelist

$data1
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  V1        
  <chr>     
1 1|2|3|4|5 
2 6|7|8|9|10

$data2
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  V1            
  <chr>         
1 6|7|8|9|10    
2 11|12|13|14|15

$data3
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  V1            
  <chr>         
1 16|17|18|19|20
2 21|22|23|24|25


Either of the two commands below should give the desired output:
map(filelist, ~ separate(.x, 
    cols=V1, 
    into=c(paste0("column_", letters[1:5])), 
    sep="\\|"))

map(filelist, ~ separate_wider_delim(.x, 
    cols=V1, 
    names=c(paste0("column_", letters[1:5])), 
    delim="|"))


$data1
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  column_a column_b column_c column_d column_e
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 1        2        3        4        5       
2 6        7        8        9        10      

$data2
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  column_a column_b column_c column_d column_e
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 6        7        8        9        10      
2 11       12       13       14       15      

$data3
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  column_a column_b column_c column_d column_e
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 16       17       18       19       20      
2 21       22       23       24       25 


Thank you! For some reason it didn't like cols=V1, but just specifying just V1 worked.
filesepd = map(filelist, ~ separate(.x,
V1,
into=c(paste0("column_", letters[1:20])),
sep="\|"))
